# Sequelize targetKey doesn't seem to be taking effect with belongsToMany

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

Are there any know issues with belongsToMany and targetKey option?

**My model def looks like this:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Keyword = sequelize.define('Keyword', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Keyword.associate = function(models) {
    Keyword.belongsToMany(models.Location, {
      through: models.SearchRequest
    })

    Keyword.belongsToMany( models.Ranking, {
      targetKey: 'searchRequestId',
      otherKey: {
        name: 'id'
      },
      through: {
        model: models.SearchRequest,
      }
    })
  }
  return Keyword;
};
```

**After running the commands below:**

```
kwrr > keyword = await Keyword.findOne()()
kwrr > await keyword.getRankings()
```

**The sql produced looks like this:**

```
Executing (default): 
SELECT 
`Ranking`.`id`, `Ranking`.`googlePageRank`, `Ranking`.`googleResultRank`, 
`Ranking`.`searchRequestId`, `Ranking`.`createdAt`, `Ranking`.`updatedAt`, 
`SearchRequest`.`locationId` AS `SearchRequest.locationId`, `SearchRequest`.`keywordId` AS 
`SearchRequest.keywordId`, `SearchRequest`.`websiteId` AS `SearchRequest.websiteId`, 
`SearchRequest`.`createdAt` AS `SearchRequest.createdAt`, `SearchRequest`.`updatedAt` AS 
`SearchRequest.updatedAt`, `SearchRequest`.`KeywordId` AS `SearchRequest.KeywordId`, 
`SearchRequest`.`LocationId` AS `SearchRequest.LocationId`
FROM `Rankings` AS `Ranking` 
  INNER JOIN `SearchRequests` AS `SearchRequest` 
    ON `Ranking`.`id` = `SearchRequest`.`id` AND 
   `SearchRequest`.`KeywordId` = 101;
```

I’m expecting Ranking.searchRequestId instead of Ranking.id. So `INNER JOIN SearchRequests AS SearchRequest ON Ranking.searchRequestId = SearchRequest.id`.

According [to the source](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/83e263bd4f97860e37cfd8c4a69995a3901b9264/types/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.d.ts#L72), it targetKey should enable one to do so.

**Any idea why it's not taking effect?**

p.s I followed through the source, and targetKey's value is being passed in as expected, but the sql produced doesn't seem to honor it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I missing something? I see no association between Ranking and SearchRequest, nor a `findAll()`

Comment: @KenOn10 the association is in `Keyword.associate`. I also clarified the post to show the commands executed that produced the sql.